# Unpivot to create multple columns

Tags: google-bigquery, unpivot

I have this table .....

```
match  |player1  |player2  |player3 |position1  |position2  |position3 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
54575  |234      |568      |98000   |535        |78758      |8686586   |
```

and i want to make unpivot (with BIGQUERY)  to have his output :

```
match  |player  |position 
--------------------------
54575  |234      |535     
54575  |568      |78758   
54575  |98000    |8686586
```

I try this query ( https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unpivot_operator )

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  match UNPIVOT(id FOR player IN (player1,
      player2,
      player3))
```

AND i have this result :

```
product |position1 |position2 |position3|id   |player   
----------------------------------------------------
54575   |  535     |78758     |8686586  |234  |player1
54575   |  535     |78758     |8686586  |568  |player2
54575   |  535     | 78758    |8686586  |98000|player3
```

Comment: You can use `SELECT product as match, id, player` instead of `SELECT *` and it will give you what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option without **UNPIVOT**

```sql
SELECT match, pp.* 
  FROM sample, UNNEST([
    STRUCT(player1 AS player, position1 AS position),
          (player2, position2),
          (player3, position3)
  ]) pp;
```

output will be:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use `UNPIVOT`

```
SELECT * FROM table_1
UNPIVOT(
  (players, positions) 
  FOR player_position 
  IN  ((player1, position1), (player2, position2), (player3, position3))
)
```

**Output**

| match | players | positions | player_position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54575 | 234 | 535 | player1_position1 |
| 54575 | 568 | 78758 | player2_position2 |
| 54575 | 98000 | 8686586 | player3_position3 |

Comment: use `SELECT * EXCEPT(player_position) FROM table_1` to eliminate extra column